# authProvider is finishing its Promise after the Dashboard being mounted

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

Using [react-admin]

I have a customDashboard that verifies a parameter and redirect to the a page called `pages`:

```
class DashBoard extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    const { push } = this.props;
    if (!localStorage.getItem("activePage")) {
        push("/pages");
    }
    ...
```

I also have this authProvider that fetches authentication data from backend:

```
export default (type, params) => {
if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
    const { authResponse } = params;
    const request = new Request('https://localhost:8080/users/auth', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ userID }),
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    });
    fetch(request)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                throw new Error(response.body);
             }
             return response.json();
        }).then(({ user }) => {
              localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
              localStorage.setItem('name', user.name);
              localStorage.setItem('email', user.email);
              localStorage.setItem('activePage', user.activePage);
        }).catch((err) => {
              return Promise.reject(err);
        }).finally(() => {
              return Promise.resolve();});
        ...
```

I stripped down the code to show only the Promises part.

However, the last part of the code, the `finally`, is being executed AFTER `“/pages”` gets mounted, as I saw in the console.log. And, in `“/pages”` I check the activePage returned by the backend, what is happening too late.

What is missing in the authProvider to “await” the promises get finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `async/await`, it's bit easier to follow the flow:

```
export default async (type, userID) => {
  if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {
    try  {
      const res =  await fetch('https://localhost:8080/users/auth', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ userID })
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
      }) // fetch API data

      const { user: { token, name, email, activePage } } = await res.json(); // convert to JSON, from the JSON's user prop, pull out token, name, email, activePage

      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      localStorage.setItem('name', name);
      localStorage.setItem('email', email);
      localStorage.setItem('activePage', activePage);

    } catch(err) { console.error(err); }
  }
}
```

Comment: reduced the boilerplate, nice answer.

Comment: Just a small heads up: If you ever plan on pushing this to production, then you'll need a better way of defining your `API` url. Hard coding `http://localhost:8080` in the `fetch` request won't work in production!

Comment: Sure. I tried to use a process.env, however the react-admin and create-react-app does not use the .env as a common node application. When come the time to release it to production I am gonna look for a proper solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855756/how-to-call-auth-check-after-auth-login-fetch-is-complete) and did some changes in my code. Now it works fine:

- The default function is `async`, calls an `auth` function and returns a Promise in the end.

  ```
  // in src/authProvider.js
  export default async (type, params) => {
      if (type === AUTH_LOGIN) {    
          const { authResponse } = params;
          const user = await auth(userID);
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          if (user.activePage) localStorage.setItem('activePage', user.activePage);

          return Promise.resolve();
  ```
- The `auth` function returns a Promise:

  ```
  const auth = async (userID) => {
    const request = new Request('https://localhost:8080/users/auth', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ userID }),
      headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    });

    return fetch(request)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
          throw new Error(response.body);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(({ user }) => {
        return user;
      });
  }
  ```